# How to reduce processing speed of excel file in c#

Tags: c#, excel

We are having a excel data Invoice input of 3 million customers every month to be processed.
There are only 8 fields in the data.  Now the time consumed in processing to PDF format is too big & we are not able to meet the TAT.
Can anyone suggest any input to reduce processing speed?

Comment: I guess "processing time"))

Comment: yes, I want to reduce "processing time"

Answer (score 2):

There are several possibilities to reduce processing time.

Please check before what the bottleneck is.

To reduce processing time here are some ideas:

- Use TPL to parallelize processing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_Extensions#Task_Parallel_Library
- Maybe use a thirdparty library to process excel files (e.g. Aspose.Cells, Aspose.PDF)
- When the hardware is the bottleneck => use SSD and a better CPU or use CUDA to process https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA